# Ubuntu 14.10(Utopic Unicorn), Displays menu is Broken?

Tags: unity, upgrade, vlc, system-settings, 14.10

I recently upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04 from the software center, 2 days later I changed my Desktop Background from Settings-Displays , I may have updated the system with minor 3 to 10 MB updates from software center after that, I guess. No major changes made.

Now when I try to change the Desktop Background again, it shows the **Displays panel is broken**.

It is *transparent* Except for the menu bar and shows "**Could Not get Screen Information"**

Moreover, even the **settings** menu  frame seems to be **broken**, the **resize icon** in the bottom right is **missing** and I am unable to resize it.

Now how do I change my desktop background and how to fix this issue?
Also **VLC Audio** had issues after 14.10 upgrade , I resolved by reinstalling pulsa drivers, could this also have been due to the Upgrade?

**NOTE** : I am using the latest version of Binary tested Nvidia Drivers,
I had absolutely no issues whatsoever with 14.04

Aren’t releases such as 14.10 supposed to be *Stable too even though they are not* *LTS*  or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed in an update :) ,
never mind

Answer (score 7):

I had also the same problem in Ubuntu-14.10.  I solved it by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

type with these commands and see if it is working:

```
                       sudo apt-get update
                       sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
                       sudo apt-get install unity
                       sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: sorry i just tried it again and it worked , i guess i didn't do it properly the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer for that situation but you can usually find out (or get around it) with some troubleshooting:

Most of the upgrade issues are caused by some former settings / config files not being handled gracefully by the newer version of a package. Packages do their best to either be backwards compatible or migrate user's settings so that everything continues to work seamlessly after an upgrade. However this can be hard to test and so a frequent source of bugs.

To confirm this, **create a new user and log back in as that user**. If the problem is gone you know it's one of your regular user's settings that's doing it.

Alternatively if you're familiar with command line you can test with same user:
- log out + log back in using the console (<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd>)
- rename your home folder and create a new one
- log back in and see if you can replicate the issue

If that's the case first **backup your home directory** then you can either:

- start putting your config files back (the .files in your home dir, `ls -d ~/.??*` )
  and see which one is triggering it (do a binary search if there's a lot). It's likely going to be something in `.gconf` or `.config` in which case you have to dig deeper.
- or start from scratch and just import / replicate the settings your care about.

Comment: hey ,tell me a way to correct without creating a new user and stuff

Comment: I hope someone comes up with the answer you're looking for, in the meantime it's going to be a lot easier to help you if you take basic troubleshooting steps.