# Ubuntu "Could not get screen information" after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, xorg, display

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 and now when I open Display Settings I get the message "Could Not get Screen Information"(here is a screenshot): [image: Could not get Screen information]

There are multiple questions related to that and I think [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/547483/110892)
was most useful. I logged in with another user and for him the Display settings menu works just fine. So following the answer I get to the conclusion: `It's likely going to be something in .gconf or .config in which case you have to dig deeper.` The problem is that I don't know how to dig deeper.

I have already tried solutions in many other answers. I have reinstalled nvidia drivers, ubuntu-desktop, xorg, xserver-xorg and all other tips from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)(short of fresh install that I really want to avoid).

I am using ubuntu 16.04(4.4.0-31-generic amd64) on lenovo w530 laptop. Any ideas on how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you do a `ps x|grep control-center` command in a terminal window, you may expect *gnome-control-center* as result. Close this control center window and instead type `unity-control-center` in a terminal window.

This control center will show your screen information. Pin it in the launcher for future use and possibly pin out the former one.

Comment: I am using the display menu in settings. Am I supposed to pin out "Settings" launcher?

Comment: The update to 16.10 completely removed the unity-control-center and only left the gnome-control-center - very weird. Installed the latter and removed the former, now the displays are shown - but the online-accounts button is missing. Classic Linux tinkery.

Comment: I had the same issue, in 16.04, suddenly, when attaching a new display. This answer solved my issue.

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center` if needed.

Comment: How to set the image

Comment: I would have upvoted x2 if it was possible! :)

Answer (score 13):

reinstalling the Unity Control center worked for me :

> sudo apt remove unity-control-center
>
> sudo apt install unity-control-center

(Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity)

Comment: There are dependencies that could result in problems. 
`The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon`
Give `apt-get install unity-control-center --reinstall` a try instead.

Answer (score 8):

I've some trick for this:
right click on screen, choose "Change desktop background", click on "All settings" and go to "Displays".

This way it's works for me, but through Settings -> Display doesn't

Comment: ya strange but this works for me too

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with 16.10. At some point, I did some clean up and one of the following removed `unity-control-center`:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The solution was to manually reinstall `unity-control-center`:

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

I now see 2 Settings apps in Dash: "**Settings**" (`gnome-control-center`) and "**System Settings**" (`unity-control-center`).