# Some applications not displayed in standard Ubuntu GUI or flickering under unity 8

Tags: graphics

I'm facing a strange behaviour. I need to point out first I am not a Linux/Ubuntu expert.

Some programs, like Thunderbird, Chromium or Gimp, are not being displayed. They are in the left hand-side bar and when I'm typing Alt+Tab I can see them in the list of running programs. Though, I'm seeing nothing appearing on my deskptop : no program at all.

I tried Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04, making a full reinstall each time. 17.04 is making Firefox working well while 16.04 and 16.10 are not. Though, under 17.04 Firefox add-ons like AdBlock Plus are having the same behaviour.

This is under the standard Ubuntu GUI. When I'm switching to Unity 8 on the login page, some programs are being displayed well, like Gimp, but others are not, like Thunderbird. Also, Chromium window is displayed, but flickering a lot (about 2 black frames per second I would say), so effectively I can't use Chromium. Just the inside of Chromium window is flickering, not the whole desktop.

I'm suspecting my graphical chipset being not properly configured. But maybe it's not. Here is my hardware spec :

Processor : Intel Pentium G4400
Integrated GPU : Intel HD Graphics 510
RAM : 4GO DIMM DDR4
Motherboard : Asus H110M-K
Screen : LG 22M38A

I have made a full apt update / apt upgrade, but not installed anything more than what comes with Ubuntu 17.04.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am also using almost same configuration of hardware but installed Ubuntu 16.04. Facing the same issues with GIMP and even system monitor and Bit torrent client.

Things work in guest login. but not in admin.

Someone found [a solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217862) by by updating the monitor settings.

I Found solution:

Its happening because some of the programs are opening in additional monitor.
And your system is not configured for the  right monitor.

[Ubuntu "Could not get screen information" after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808817/ubuntu-could-not-get-screen-information-after-upgrade)

1. Just shutdown the system.
2. Disconnect Monitor
3. Restart the system
4. Now connect the monitor

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have problems with GTK. All programs you said uses GTK as base UI library. Should take a look if your system is up to date and if your GTK libraries have no conflicts.

It happens a lot when you try to upgrade from very old version, or to an unstable one. May happen too when you use unstable version or use different releases.

Be sure your 17.04 is the stable one (the stable one still have many probems).