# ubuntu dual monitor error problem (after install nvidia driver)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution

1. I use ubuntu 16.04 / cuda 8.0 / gtx-1070 (nvidia-367.44 driver)
2. I used two monitor and it worked well
3. **When I install nvidia-367.44 driver, one of my monitor doesn't work**
4. ubuntu 'setting'->'display' menu doesn't work.
5. The two monitors are connected with main board (cpu intel graphic card. not gtx-1070)
6. when I connect the one(not working) to gpu instead of cpu, the monitor detect it but it doesn't work well because of resolution problem

   ### 7. How can I fix it? Actually, I want to connect two monitor to cpu not gtx. and I want to use dual monitor.

I already tried some methods 
[Cannot open "Display" settings, error "Could not get screen information"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698428/cannot-open-display-settings-error-could-not-get-screen-information) 
[Ubuntu 14.10(Utopic Unicorn), Displays menu is Broken?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544073/ubuntu-14-10utopic-unicorn-displays-menu-is-broken) 
[Ubuntu "Could not get screen information" after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808817/ubuntu-could-not-get-screen-information-after-upgrade) 
[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

How can I detect and use the another monitor well? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yeah same thing happened to me just 3-4 days ago, i spent days trying to figure it out but just couldn't. I finally completely wiped out ubuntu and reinstalled it that fixed the problem. I don't recommend installing any kind of Nvidia driver if you are using double graphic card(one integrated) dual monitor setup.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But I want to use cuda and tensorflow. So I should install nvidia driver T.T

Comment: That advice is only from my personal experience, maybe there is some way out. :) Good Luck.

Comment: I solved it.   1. I connect two monitors to GPU /  2.open NVIDIA X Server Setting (X-server Display Configuration)

Comment: GT-1070 has dual-link? I can't connect two DVI/HDMIs, i'm gonna need a converter i think.

Comment: I connected to DVI and HDMI link respectively :D